# matplotlib chart not recognising label on bar, but same code works for pie

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pivot-table

I have started with matplotlib / pandas.

I have created a pivot_table with pandas, and then visualised it with matplotlib.

[Heres a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmAAG.jpg):
[image]

Strangely, when the same data ("client_pivot") is built into two different graphs (bar and pie), they behave differently in relation to the legend/keys.

Although the bar lists the labels below. It doesn't seem to recognise them in the legend, nor does it apply the differing colour scheme. Its as though it sees them as one lot of data...

Have you any idea why this is and how I can resolve it?

Below is an extract of the relevant code (to be concise, the irrelevant code has been cut out).

```
import pandas as pd

def reportMe(event):
csv_file = pd.read_csv("file.csv",
                       names = ['USER',
                               'CLIENT',
                               'TYPE',
                               'START',
                               'END',
                               'DURATION',
                               'NOTES'])

client_pivot = csv_file.pivot_table(index="CLIENT",
                                         aggfunc="sum")

def pieMaker():
    x_client = list(client_pivot.index)
    y_duration = list(client_pivot["DURATION"])

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))

    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)

    ax1.bar(x_client, y_duration)   #bar

    for label in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
        label.set_rotation(17)

    ax1.tick_params(labelsize=7)
    ax1.legend(x_client,
               loc="center left",
               bbox_to_anchor=(0.9, 0, 0.5, 1),
               fontsize=7)
    ax1.set_ylabel('Time (s)')

    ax2.pie(y_duration,             #pie
            shadow=True,
            autopct='%1.1f%%',
            textprops={'fontsize': 7,
                       'color':'w'})
    ax2.legend(x_client,
               loc="center left",
               bbox_to_anchor=(0.9, 0, 0.5, 1),
               fontsize=7)
    ax2.set_aspect(1)

    plt.show()
pieMaker()
```

edit: added pie code in for comparison

Comment: How are you creating the legend for the pie? I suppose you are providing the wedges *and* the labels to the legend in that case? One would need to do the same for the bar.

Comment: They look the same to me:

Comment: I  have added the pie code in to the original post for comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bars are recognized as a single entity, but the pie wedges are individual entities as seen by the legend. This is a style choice; pie charts do not have a scale attached, which would be used to describe the individual patches, hence a legend with color is useful for pies. Bar plots are usually shown with the same color, such that there is only one label needed in the legend to identify the complete bar plot (and possibly distinguish from some other bar plot).

In order to have each bar individually appear in the legend you can supply those to the `handles` argument of `legend`.

In order to have the bars colorized, you may use the colors from the default color cycler and provide them as argument to `color`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)


a = .5+np.random.rand(5)
labs = list("ABCDE")

fig, (ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
ax.pie(a)
ax.legend(labels=labs)


colors = plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"].by_key()["color"]
bars = ax2.bar(labs, a, color=colors)
ax2.legend(handles=bars, labels=labs)

plt.show()
```

[image]